# Toggling character format with PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt6

I'm writing a custom word processor as a hobby project. I'm using Python and PyQt6.

I wrote the following. The intent is that if I select some text and apply Bold formatting (for example, by hitting "ctrl-b"), it will toggle the formatting. Specifically, it should remove the bold formatting if all of the selected text is bold. Otherwise, it will apply the bold formatting.

```
class OvidFont:
    def __init__(self, ovid) -> None:
        self.textEditor = ovid.textEditor

    def setBoldText(self) -> None:
        fmt = QTextCharFormat()
        if self.textEditor.currentCharFormat().fontWeight() != QFont.Weight.Bold:
            print("    setting bold")   # for debugging
            fmt.setFontWeight(QFont.Weight.Bold)
        else:
            print("    setting normal") # for debugging
            fmt.setFontWeight(QFont.Weight.Normal)
        self.textEditor.textCursor().mergeCharFormat(fmt)
```

However, it won't remove the bold formatting.

For example, in the sentence "this is a test", if I select "is a" and apply the bold formatting, I get "this **is a** test", with the "is a" properly bold. However, with the selection in place, it still remains bold if I hit "ctrl-b". If I deselect either the first or last character, the toggling of bold works as expected. (I've tried reversing the if/else logic, but that fails, too).

What am I missing?

Update: I've added a working, minimal test case at https://gist.github.com/Ovid/65936985c6838c0220620cf40ba935fa

Comment: Please add the whole minimal test-case to your question. Do not use links to external sites for this purpose. Example code [should always be provided as text within the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with `setBoldText` function was that it checked the bold status using `self.textEditor.currentCharFormat().fontWeight()`, which only reflects the formatting of the character at the current cursor position, not the entire selected text. If your cursor was at the beginning or end of the selection, it might not accurately represent the formatting of the whole selected range.

So I used the existing cursor and adjust it if necessary to check the formatting and directly apply the new font weight using `setFontWeight()` on the `QTextEdit`.

Now it looks like that:

[image]

**Updated code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QTextEdit, QToolButton, QApplication, QMainWindow, QToolBar
from PyQt6.QtGui import QFont, QShortcut, QKeySequence, QTextCharFormat, QTextCursor

class OvidFont:
    def __init__(self, ovid) -> None:
        self.textEditor = ovid.textEditor

    def setBoldText(self):
        cursor = self.textEditor.textCursor()

        # If there's a selection, and the cursor is not at the block start and at the beginning of the selection,
        # move the cursor to the end of the selection
        if cursor.hasSelection() and not cursor.atBlockStart() and cursor.position() == cursor.selectionStart():
            cursor.setPosition(cursor.selectionEnd())

        # Check if the text (either selected or where the cursor is) is bold
        is_bold = cursor.charFormat().fontWeight() == QFont.Weight.Bold

        # Apply the new weight based on the current state
        new_weight = QFont.Weight.Normal if is_bold else QFont.Weight.Bold
        self.textEditor.setFontWeight(new_weight)

        print(f"Bold set to: {'Normal' if is_bold else 'Bold'}")

class Ovid(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Ovid")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)
        self.textEditor = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEditor)
        self.fonts = OvidFont(self)

        self.toolbar = QToolBar("Main Toolbar")
        self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)

        bold_button = QToolButton()
        bold_button.setText("B")
        bold_button.setFont(QFont("Arial", 16, QFont.Weight.Bold))
        bold_button.setToolTip("Bold")
        bold_button.clicked.connect(self.fonts.setBoldText)
        self.toolbar.addWidget(bold_button)

        QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+B"), self, self.fonts.setBoldText)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ovid()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to create a new text cursor, you can just use the current one and check whether it is at the beginning of the selection (and then eventually move it to the end), which is the actual issue you are facing, because in Qt the character format is always that of the character *preceding* the cursor position (except for the first character of the paragraph). There is also no point in creating a new format, since QTextEdit already provides through [`setFontWeight()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextedit.html#setFontWeight) and similar functions.

Comment: @musicamante your point is valid. I'll adjust the answer accordingly, thank u

Comment: Also, please avoid answering questions that don't include acceptable code, especially if such code is explicitly requested and originally provided only as an external link: we almost *never* accept code in this form, because such websites may not be accessible to everybody due to country or workplace network restrictions, and repositories/pastebins may be changed/removed, making the question invalid. If you're interested in the question, click "Follow" to wait for updates, if you don't have enough reputation for closure votes (eg. to request debugging updates), flag it as "Needs improvement".

Comment: @musicamante I did not know. I will take that into consideration, thx again

Comment: Note that `at_start` in the update is wrong: if the cursor is at the block start, there's no need to move it (as said, in that case it uses the format of the first character). Returning in case of no selection is also invalid, because the user may want to set the font in bold while beginning to write a new section. In fact, you should check if a selection exists, and eventually move the cursor (without keeping the anchor, as it's irrelevant) to the end if it's not at the block start *and* at the beginning of the selection; then *always* get the format, even without selection, and change it.

Comment: it should work properly now

Comment: Sorry, but no. You're not checking anymore if the cursor is at the beginning of the selection, and you've reverted to the `mergeFormat()` instead of using `self.textEditor.setFontWeight()`. Just do `if (cursor.hasSelection() and not cursor.atBlockStart() and cursor.position() == cursor.selectionStart()):` `cursor.setPosition(cursor.selectionEnd())` then (outside of the `if` block) `is_bold = cursor.charFormat().fontWeight() == QFont.Weight.Bold` and finally `self.textEditor.setFontWeight(QFont.Weight.Normal if is_bold else QFont.Weight.Bold)`.